# Bootstrap modals and jQuery on (live)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery on event like so:

```
$('#select_search').on('change', '#parent_row', function(){
  alert("Select a county first");
});
```

It does not callback, but when I remove the second parameter '#parent_row', it works.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="row" id="parent_row">
  <div class="col-md-6">   
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 750px;">
      ...
         <select name="select_search" id="select_search" class="form-control">
            ...
```

The important point is that it is using bootstrap's modal. You press the button and a form opens up in a modal and the form has a select element. Could the modal be causing the on() not to work properly?

Comment: You have misunderstood how event delegation works in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it the wrong way around. To delegate the event, you have to register it on parent element:

```
$('#parent_row').on('change', '#select_search', function () {
     console.log('Select a county first');
});
```

Cheers.